# Difference between wrestling and grappling

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, mixed-martial-arts, grappling, terminology, wrestling

Many times, when my sensei teaches me a technique, he takes reference from either wrestling or grappling. I always thought the two are different terms for the same art until the master told me that it's not the case and wrestling is different grappling. But, I still couldn't understand the difference between the two. Can someone help me understand it clearly.

Answer (score 5):

Grappling is a more generic, umbrella term than wrestling. Striking from a Muay Thai clinch, for example, is part grappling but not wrestling.

Standard disclaimers apply, however, that people use words differently and in ways that disagree.

Answer (score 4):

Quite frankly, there is no objective difference between the two, so it's more likely simply a distinction created by your teacher. Most likely, he's differentiating between Western techniques one might see in amateur Greco-Roman wrestling, and grappling techniques seen in something like Brazilian Jujitsu.

Comment: I disagree. Wresting is a kind of grappling, but not vice versa. For example, you would be wrong to call BJJ or Judo "wrestling".

Comment: What do you see as the distinction?

Comment: I don't. Asking the difference between wrestling and grappling is like asking the difference between music and country. It's not that they are different, but one is a subcategory of the other.

Comment: {nods} That's fair. I will keep my answer up as it is, but I do appreciate your input, which agrees with mattm's answer.